# Copy objects from one database to other

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to copy all content (tables, tables data, stored procedures, triggers) from one database A to oher database B. These database contains large amount of data so unable to generate script. 
If database A contains table X and database B contains table X, Y. Then it shoud replace table X but without affecting table Y.
 If table P is dependent on table Q then it should copy table Q first then copy table P.

Is there any way to do this? Using sql server management studio or SSIS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to create a migration package with SSIS but it will be a big job if there are many tables.

I would recommend getting some 3rd party tools to help. Do a schema diff first to create the tables in database B and then run a data diff to move/merge the data.

I use Redgate tools (I have no affiliation with the company) but there are others if you look for them on the web.

Comment: Good to know that you use redgate tool, I think its called something like schema Compare. I just wanted to know what size of database is it that you do schema compare with redgate (Approximately number of tables and approximately number of rows in your database), and how long it takes.

Comment: And can you set up a task in redgate to do this schema and data compare jobs at fix intervals like every 15 minutes or so ???

Comment: @M.Ali - The database I have used the tools on has about 115 objects (tables, procedures, views etc) and the largest table about 4.5m rows. The SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare tools work quite quickly although I've never recorded how long it takes.  I would not use them (and I'm not sure it's possible to) for scheduled updates; use replication for those situations.